# Dynamic className in map not changing after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update my react `className` when the `active` changes in the `sites` variable which is mapped to loop through the items.

What happens is that the `className` 'inactive' does not go away if the active status changes to `true` or visa versa.

Code:

```
// Context: this code is inside of the component
const [sites, setSites] = useState([]);  <--- Updated dynamically with fetch()
const changeActive = (id) => {
   const tmpSites = sites;
   for (const s in tmpSites) {
      if (tmpSites[s].id === id) {
         tmpSites[s].active = !Boolean(tmpSites[s].active);
      }
   }
   setSites(tmpSites);
};

return (
    {sites.length ? sites.map((item, i) => {
       return (
          <tr className={`${!Boolean(item.active) ? 'inactive' : ''}`} key={item.id}>
              // inbetween data
          </tr>
       )
    }) : null}
)
```

Comment: You need to *debug* this by using `useEffect` with dependency Array for `[sites]` and make sure the item `active` property actually changes. Your code seems fine

Comment: Can you show usage `changeActive`?

Comment: `className={item.active ? ''" : "inactive"}` is shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a copy of the `sites` array, make changes to the copy, and then set it in the state. Never mutate the state directly, as it may not trigger a re-render if we update the state with the same object reference.

```js
const changeActive = (id) => {
   const tmpSites = [...sites];
   for (const s in tmpSites) {
      if (tmpSites[s].id === id) {
         tmpSites[s].active = !Boolean(tmpSites[s].active);
      }
   }
   setSites(tmpSites);
};
```

Comment: This worked! I can't believe I didn't think of this...

Comment: This does not do deep clone, and while it works, it is flawed in few ways

Answer (score 0):

Because you are mutating the original sites Object and not cloning it before making the changes, the `useState` (*"setSites"*) does not actually re-renders the component because it cannot compare previous Object to current, because they are the same.

You must do a deep-clone of the `sites` Array of Objects:

```js
const changeActive = (id) => {
   setSites(sites => 
     sites.map(site => ({  // ← first-level clone
        ...site            // ← second-level clone
        active: site.id === id ? !site.active : site.active
     ))
   })
}
```

It is imperative to use the `setSites` function that returns the **current** state and then you can **reliably** deep-clone it.